# Find $D^*$ from Hoffman and Kunze Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on the following problem.

"Let $V$ be the inner product space of Exercise 8, and let $D$ be the differentiation operator on $V$. Find $D^*$."

When the question asks us to "find $D^*$", does it mean to find the matrix of $D^*$? I hope that is what it means because that is precisely what I have done.

By the way in Exercise 8, $V$ is the vector space of the polynomial with the inner product $$(f|g) = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)dt$$.

Comment: If $V$ is really the vector space of polynomials, then $V$ is infinite-dimensional.  What would the matrix of an operator over $V$ even look like?

Comment: I would be very curious to see what "matrix" you came up with here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I should have mentioned that $V$ is the vector space of the polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree less than or equal to 3..

Comment: Well, then yes: you should have mentioned that.  Even so, you need to be careful if you're using the matrix of $D$ to get the matrix of $D^*$.  Note in particular that $D^*$ will only be the transpose of $D$ if you found $D$ with respect to an orthogonal (or orthonormal) basis.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I found an orthonormal basis by Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization (which took a long time of computation), found the matrix $D$ with respect to this basis, and then took the transpose to get $D^*$. But, as you have mentioned, I now believe that this is not what the question is asking. I also think that the question is asking to find $D*$ in a general sense. I will try to do this using your hint below.

Comment: I think your answer is probably what they're actually looking for, especially since they have specified the vector space.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Just to hit the point home, D* is not unique, right? D* can vary depending on the basis we picked, right? Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: No! $D^*$ **is** unique. It depends on the inner product, not the basis.

Comment: The matrix you get for $D^*$ (just like the matrix for $D$) depends on the basis, though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, that is the matrix of $D*$ (or "$D$) depends on the basis. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note from my above comment that a matrix of the transformation $D$ or $D^*$ would need infinitely many rows and columns.  Because $V$ is a space of countable dimension, this at least makes some sense.  However, it is unlikely that a matrix is what the asker expects.

What I think the question means is find the transformation $D^*$ as a function on polynomials.  On an inner product space $V$, we define $D^*$ to be the transformation satisfying
$$
(Df|g) = (f|D^*g)
$$
for every $f,g \in V$.  In particular, we are looking for a linear transformation $D^*$ such that
$$
\int_0^1 [Df(t)]g(t)\,dt = \int_0^1 f(t)[D^*g(t)]\,dt
$$

---

**Hint:** The integration by parts formula tells us that
$$
\int_0^1 [Df(t)]g(t)\,dt =
f(1)g(1)-f(0)g(0) - \int_0^1 f(t)Dg(t)\,dt
$$

Comment: I got to the point where I deduced from the above hint that, $\int_0^1 f(t) \cdot (D^*[g(t)] + D[g(t)]) dt = f(1)g(1) - f(0)g(0)$. But I think I am stuck here. How do we find $D^*$ explicitly here? Thanks..

Comment: I think that $D^*$ can be defined by $D^*g= -Dg + g(0)p(t) + g(1)q(t)$ for some polynomials $p(t),q(t)$.